# Urls amigáveis com dez variáveis da erro

Tags: php, apache, url

Quando se coloca 10 variáveis da erro

```
RewriteRule ^client/product/([a-z0-9-]+)/([a-z0-9-]+)/([a-z0-9-]+)/([a-z0-9-]+)/([a-z0-9-]+)/([a-z0-9-]+)/([a-z0-9-]+)/([a-z0-9-]+)/([a-z0-9-]+)/([a-z0-9-]+)/?$ ikoopcore/client/product.php?name=$1&price=$2&type=$3&date=$4&category=$5&city=$6&state=$7&region=$8&rayauth_user_id=$9&rayauth_token=$10 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Qual erro em especifico?

Comment: se eu colocar $9 tudo funciona mas com $10 não

Comment: Pode ser o limite de 'retrovisores' da regex.

Answer (score 1):

Em expressões regulares  back references ou retrovisores tem o limite de 9, quando você tenta acessar `$10` ou `\10` o apache interpreta como `$1`, nesse caso é necessário rescrever a lógica.

**Referências:**

[RewriteRule using $10, $11, $12, and so on](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5849017/1342547)

[mod_rewrite number of parameters/back-references limitation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/715069/1342547)

Comment: Como resolvo isso de maneira pratica?